# Visual Basic Randomize() vs New Random

Tags: vb.net, random

It seems that `Randomize()` & `Rnd()` aren't used anymore.

Instead people make something like:

```
Dim rng as New Random()
Dim randomNo as Integer = rng.Next(10) ' this is a random number between 0 and 10.
Dim anotherRandomNo as Integer = rng.Next(10) ' a different random number.
```

Could someone tell me why this is considered "better" in most circumstances?

Comment: Please lay out your code as code, not plaint text in the question.

Comment: FYI: `rng.Next(10)` produces an integer between `0` and `9` inclusive.

Comment: `Randomize()` and `Rnd()` are there for backward compatibility for VB6 (pre-.NET). To say they aren't used anymore is really to say they were obsolete in 2001. It's now 17 years later and they should be well and truly dead. The `Random` class is part of the BCL. The classes inside `System.Security.Cryptography` are where you really want to be if you're doing anything that requires strong crypto random numbers.

Comment: Thanks very much that's really helpful

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons.

`Random` has much greater functionality .. Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Also and more importantly the old `Randomize` is built into the instantiation of a `Random` object. By default, `Rnd` without randomize always started with the same seed number. If you didn't use randomize at the start of your program, each time it ran, it would generate the same sequence of numbers.

Finally, internally the `Random` object generates numbers in a different way with a better spread of randomness.